# Newbie Problem Python: Why did the index value change?

Tags: python

I was doing the exercises from the PY4E textbook. In the string section, we had an exercise where we have to print out the characters of a string backwards.

I think the code was good enough until I executed the program. While debugging, I found out that the value of the index suddenly became -7.

I know putting an if and break statement will fix this but I just wanted to know why did this happen. Advance Thanks!

[image: screen capture of browser tab with code on programiz]

Comment: Please *do not post images of code*. Post code as formatted text in the question itself. See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) for how to format code-blocks

Comment: A more pythonic way of reversing a string is by using slice operation `reverse = original_string[::-1]`. The order of operators stands for: `[from : to : by]` where `from` is 0 by default and `to` is the end of the string by default. This way we're essentally reading the string from the end in reverse order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try the following code:

```py
while index >= 0: # or > -1
    letter = fruit[index]
    print(letter, index)
    index = index - 1
```

In your case, you are repeating the `while` while the index is less than the length of the string. This will forever be true because you are decrementing index by 1. `0 < len(fruit)` and `-1 < len(fruit)` and `-2 < len(fruit)`, etc.

The reason that doing `fruit[-1]` does not raise an `IndexError` is because negative indices basically mean *from the back*. The error only gets raised when `index = -7` because there is no 7th value from the back in `"banana"`.

So you could also rewrite your code to be:

```py
index = 1
while index <= len(fruit):
    letter = fruit[-index]
    print(letter, len(fruit) - index)
    index = index + 1
```

---

Small tip for your program, you could rewrite `index = index - 1` in a more conventional way like:

```py
index -= 1
```

This works with any other operator too: `+= ...`, `/= ...`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your `len(fruit)` will be 6, and `index < len(fruit)` will always return true, as you are starting with 5 and decrementing its value in each iteration of your loop.  Getting a negative index in python will start at the right and move left, since there are 6 characters, you get an `IndexError` for -7 as that character would be before the word "banana", which does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You mean, why did it *fail* at -7? How it *got* there is easy - you just kept subtracting one, each iteration.

Negative list indices are valid in python. Whereas `lst[0]` means the first element of `lst`, `lst[-1]` means the *last* element instead. As a consequence, a list that has `n` elements has valid positive indices up to `(n-1)`, and negative indices down to `-n`.

You get an `IndexError` whenever you try to access a list index that's outside the list. In this case, any index higher than 5 (the list has six elements, so the last index is 5) or lower than -6 (the list has six elements, so the "sixth-to-last" element is the first one in the list), will cause an `IndexError` to occur.

The other answer has given some practical solutions to this problem, as stated. Personally I'd prefer a `for` loop:

```
for char in reversed(fruit):
    print(char)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this instead:

```
for i in reversed(range(len(fruit))):
    letter = fruit[index]
    print(letter, index)
```

What happened was that you're creating an infinite loop as index will always be less than the length of fruit since you're decrementing index.

It stopped at 6 since that is the maximum negative index (Python supports negative indexing) for the word 'banana'.

For this, I think you would have printed:
a
n
a
n
a
b
a
n
a
n
a
b

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, the code is doing precisely what you told it to do: while `index` is less than the length of `fruit`, do `letter = fruit[index]`. It does not check if `index` goes negative!